# How would it be possible for a kaiju size carnivore dinosaur to survive with no eyes?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, fauna

So I'm almost done with my draft of a story I'm writing. And I just got a random question popped into my head. Is it possible for Zues (the kaiju size dino) to survive? I already got a little bit of backstory on him. He was already born without his right eye, and to add on to that he lost his other eye in a battle for territory. So how would it for him to survive with no eyes? How would he hunt? How would he navigate? If you wonder what dino he is, He is a giganotosaurus.

Comment: It can't see so it is prone to trip and fall, also it is difficult to master echolocation clicks with that massive tongue.

Comment: "***Zues** (the kaiju size dino) to survive*" the only references to "Zues" I can find are misspellings of the Greek god "Zeus".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It may be impossible***
First answer three questions:

First, How good are its other senses/echolocation?
If they are good, then it can just use that instead of sight, no problems. **your monster will survive!**

Second, is the only food source large enough to feed a monster other monsters?
If so, unless the monster out classes every other monster by a long shot they are screwed. The monster can fight blind, and other big monsters are not hard to hear, however it can not consistently win against opponents that are about as good at fighting as it is. **your monster will die**

Third, does it's food supply consist mostly of normal sized animals?
If not, and hunting is actually hard, then there is no grantee it can still hunt them, **your monster will die**. But if it is hunting normal animals it still has a chance, read below.

**Once you deal with the problems every big monster faces, hunting, navigating, and surviving would be easy.**

*Hunting*

Kaiju are giant monsters who are great at killing. The whole point of most of these movies is that in many cases the monsters don't care about humans, and are just moving through or on to a greater goal. If the Kaiju can move faster than most animals can run it can just move in a line until it goes over a horizon and do donuts to depopulate an area until it has enough food.

*Navigating*

Kaiju are giant monsters, if there is somewhere they need to go on a small island they can just walk around randomly until they get there. if there is a place they go seasonally they can make a ravine with a claw, and because they are so massive they know the only thing that could cause a ravine as small and deep is their claw, so they can use that to navigate.

*Surviving*

The main thing about Kaiju is they are apex predators. the only thing that attacks them are other kaiju. So as long as your kaiju uses the run away move whenever it is confronted with an actual threat, the monster will be fine.